# How to modify or change shape of dropdownitem in flutter? and if possible how to create like this image

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

[Design Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiAiS.png)

The above image is how I want to create it.

```
   child: Theme(
                      data: ThemeData(
                        canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                      ),
                      child: ButtonTheme(
                        alignedDropdown: true,
                        child: DropdownButton<DropDownModel>(
                          elevation: 0,
                          value: data,
                          hint: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                              start: screenUtil.setWidth(20.0),
                            ),
                            height: screenUtil.setHeight(20),
                            child: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                .translate(PLEASE_SELECT)
                                .getPleaseSelectStyle(screenUtil),
                          ),
                          onChanged: (value) {
                            setState(
                                  () {
                                secondList.addAll(list);
                                secondList.forEach(
                                      (data) {
                                    data.isSelected = false;
                                    if (data.mobileNumber ==
                                        value.mobileNumber) {
                                      value.isSelected = true;
                                      data.isSelected = value.isSelected;
                                    }
                                  },
                                );
                                list.clear();
                                list.addAll(secondList);
                                secondList.clear();
                                data = value;
                              },
                            );
                          },
                          selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
                            return list
                                .map<Widget>((DropDownModel modelData) {
                              return Column(
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Padding(
                                    child: AppLocalizations.of(context)
                                        .translate(PLEASE_SELECT)
                                        .getPleaseSelectStyle(screenUtil),
                                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                      top: screenUtil.setHeight(20.0),
                                      end: screenUtil.setHeight(30.0),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Padding(
                                    padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
                                      top: screenUtil.setHeight(10.0),
                                      start: screenUtil.setHeight(18.0),
                                    ),
                                    child: "${modelData.mobileNumber}"
                                        .getDropDownTextStyle(screenUtil),
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                            }).toList();
                          },
                          isExpanded: true,
                          isDense: true,
                          items: list.map((DropDownModel modelData) {
                            return DropdownMenuItem<DropDownModel>(
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery
                                    .of(context)
                                    .size
                                    .width,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                    Radius.circular(10.0),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Container(
                                      child: ListTile(
                                        leading: modelData.isSelected
                                            ? Icon(
                                          Icons.check_circle,
                                          color: Colors.green,
                                        )
                                            : Icon(Icons.trip_origin),
                                        title: "${modelData.mobileNumber}"
                                            .getDropDownTextStyle(
                                            screenUtil),
                                      ),
                                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                                          Radius.circular(10.0),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              value: modelData,
                            );
                          }).toList(),
                          icon: Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                right: screenUtil.setWidth(10.0),
                                bottom: screenUtil.setHeight(25.0)),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.keyboard_arrow_down,
                              size: screenUtil.setSp(20.0),
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
```

I have tried with Theme widget and expansion panel. Theme widget just able to change the background color of the item but does not able to replicate the look of the mentioned image. The expansion panel is also caused issues such as able to change header color but not able to change the background of dropdown icon color and decoration to the whole header.

Resulted Output

[code Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YlSsq.png)

Comment: You can use ```ExpansionTile``` 
https://flutter.dev/docs/catalog/samples/expansion-tile-sample

Comment: I did try Expansion tile but not getting expected Output as well as also need functionality like onTap outside of dropdownmenu ,it should be closed,Expansion tile doesn't provide any controller or Status, but ExpansionPanel does provide this but it also has issues as mention in question.